# PowerShell 'Invoke-Expression' command with single quotation

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I am trying to invoke the following the command which contains the single quotation, but I am not able to execute and returns as an error:

```
$expression = $snapshot.properties.activities[1].typeProperties.parameters.rawinputlocation = '$$Text.Format(`'wasb://document.blob.co
re.windows.net/{0:yyyy}/{0:MM}/{0:dd}/DocumentActivity/raw/{{*}}.csv'`, SliceEnd)'

 Invoke-Expression $expression
```

Error:

- Invoke-Expression $expression
- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  - CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParseException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand

Comment: Create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As of now, all there is is a code fragment that doesn't do much sense.

Comment: See also *[Invoke-Expression considered harmful](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/)*.

Answer (score 0):

This happens as the single quote, `'`, is escaped with a backtick, `` ` ``.

The first one works, but the latter one is in the wrong order: the backtick is *after* the single quote. Consider the difference:

```
`'wasb://...csv'`
`'wasb://...csv`'
```

Comment: I have checked with the first one but still no difference. Not working